# PWA app to detect when camera on mobile has taken a picture

Tags: events, mobile, camera, upload, progressive-web-apps

I want to launch a Progressive Web App whenever a camera on a mobile device has taken a picture.
When a picture is taken I want to captured extra metadata and upload the picture to a server in the cloud and the metadata to a database in the cloud. I know how to upload pictures and metadata.
I want to launch the Progressive Web App when pictures are taken to enable the user to enter extra metadata and store the picture in the cloud.
Is it possible and where can I find information on how to accomplish this?